# Eclipse plugin args

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, args, qt-jambi

When working with plugins for eclipse, I want to use QTjambi for my plugin then I tried to start it with the code below.
The args are no avaiable for me, but the QApplication.initialize(args) needs it, otherwise it doesn't launch, what to do?

```
public class View extends ViewPart{

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        Form f = new Form();
        f.wid.show();
        QApplication.exec();
    }

    public void setFocus(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what sort of arguments does it need?

Comment: in a test in another application, I printed the output for args, and make this:
System.out.println(String.valueOf(args));
String[] a = {"[Ljava.lang.String", "@15db9742"};
QApplication.initialize(a);

where the 'a' is the output for the first print

Comment: What Jambi version are you using? http://git.smar.fi/qtjambi-community.git/blob/master/INSTALL.md shows some basic ways about how to run Jambi programs.

Comment: using this stable version http://qtjambi.org/downloads with eclipse you need to import the qtjambi-4.6.3.jar, qtjambi-linux64-gcc-4.6.3.jar and qtjambi-util-4.6.3.jar
then https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-yg7SOxzI8pNWVwRXkyWEtsRUE&usp=sharing import this code on eclipse and run

Comment: I suggest to use 4.8 releases, they are more stable than 4.6 release anyway (in case they don’t work, please poke me in some way), I’m going to release non-beta-flagged release of them soon.

Comment: Anyway, the logic you’re using for running seems ok, please paste the stack trace you get so I can see what’s going wrong.

Comment: when using the 4.8.5, get this: http://pastebin.com/zBK9NG6b
on the functional code

Comment: SIGILL sounds really wrong... OpenJDK 8 is apparently official Oracle JDK? I haven’t used that myself still, so I don’t know if there is any quirks, as there is no Icedtea version of it. Can you reproduce that bug using CLI? If so, could you create a bug at http://redmine.smar.fi/projects/qtjambi ? Also, is the error same with 4.6 release? Can you try with older JDK? Your distro is?

Comment: Using this https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=jdk8-openjdk, my distro is arch linux updated. In the version 4.6.3 the bug does not happen. 
"Can you reproduce that bug using CLI?" What do you mean exactly?
sorry by bad english

Comment: Hi, sorry about late response, I didn’t check this up (faster is to contact through email or IRC). You can find general instructions how to run it here http://git.smar.fi/qtjambi-community.git/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: I got another person with arch to test this and the CLI gave correct output; libpng15.so is missing. I just added a commit to trunk that bundles libpng, so I’ll push new package for 64 bit linux now.

Comment: The same error occurs when I use java 7:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fce464d228c, pid=2496, tid=140524160096000

Comment: Could you try with release http://qtjambi.org/posts/qt-jambi-4-8-6-for-linux ?

Comment: with this release the error does not occours (and fonts are looking MUCH better), i'll try it for de plugin and post soon

Comment: i've got this while trying to launch the plugin http://pastebin.com/kh3A1A7b

Comment: How you are running the software? Does `java -cp qtjambi-4.8.6.jar:qtjambi-examples-4.8.6.jar:qtjambi-native-linux64-gcc-4.8.6.jar com.trolltech.launcher.Launcher` work on the directory where you extracted the archive?

Comment: Uhm, and, what’s the plugin? If you are using the closed source Eclipse integration, we can’t support it as it was tied to Qt versions and were never opened. We’d need someone to write new plugin for us for that.

Comment: the launccher works perfectly.
i'm not using none plugin for integration, just import the .jar, add for the classpath (on the plugin development perspective), add for runtime and makes it (the .jar) to be included in the binary build for the plugin

Comment: I’d really like to see you to try launch tha from CLI, using similar command used to launch examples. If it works like that, it’s about how you’ve configured Eclipse, which is not something I can help with.

Comment: look at this http://pastebin.com/z4DMDhEP

Comment: Okay, could you pastebin `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo http://pastebin.com/VFVcqC2R

Comment: Right, guess the build is broken. I’ll build new version that should work properly with older CPUs.

Comment: Okay, could you test with http://unofficial.qt-jambi.org/qtjambi-4.8.6.1-linux64.tar.xz ?